# Issue with Scanner picking up an user input at end of program

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

After learning .Net, I decided to have my hand at Java.
A little bit after recreating my Hello World, I decided to make a program that may have some limited use. It appears to run well enough until I give it the option to restart where `input.nextline()` seems to be completely ignored and it just loops indefinitely. Below I submit my small program designed to help my daughter in math.

```
package sndgrdmth;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class sndgrd {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Boolean bool = true;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rand = new Random();
    while (bool == true) {

        System.out.println("Enter the highest number to add with:");
        String str = input.nextLine();

        while (isNum(str) == false) {
            System.out
            .println("Not a valid number.\rEnter your high number:");
            str = input.nextLine();
        }

        int i = Integer.parseInt(str);
        int counter = 0;
        int topCounter = 5;

        while (counter < topCounter) {
            int a = rand.nextInt(i);
            int b = rand.nextInt(i);
            System.out.println(a + " + " + b + " = ?");
            int j = input.nextInt();

            if (j == a + b) {
                ++counter;
                System.out.println("Correct Answer " + counter + " of "
                        + topCounter + "!!!");
            } else {
                --counter;
                System.out.println("Incorrect Answer " + a + " + " + b
                        + " = " + (a + b) + "\rLose one point.");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Congrats! You Win! Do you want to play again? (Y/N)");
//The next line seems to get skipped.
        String repeat = input.nextLine();

        if ((repeat == "N") || (repeat == "n")) {
            bool = false;
        }else{
            bool = true;
        }
    }
    input.close();
}

public static boolean isNum(String strNum) {
    boolean ret = true;
    try {

        Double.parseDouble(strNum);

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        ret = false;
    }
    return ret;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `nextLine()` use the `next()`, that is because after you got the last int of the test using the `input.nextInt();` it will only consume the `int` not the `'\n'` so by the time you call `input.nextLine();` it will consume the '\n' and then continue to the next block of code.

**solution:**

change all your `nextLine()` to `next()`.